# Can not drag a draggable outside of another div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jquery ui draggable/droppable.

I have disabled all z-index in my css.

I try to drag a green rectangle div to the left side with the big green divs.

I can NOT move the dragged div outside the sidebar. It seems it is captured inside its parent which is the sidebar.

Why is that? What could make that happen?

I can not provide a pen/fiddle due to nda etc...

[image]

Comment: overflow: visible ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656258/jquery-dragging-outside-parent

Comment: You are my lifesaver! I had somewhere in the parent overflow:hidden; but I can not statically remove it else the sidebar is broken when animated :/ I need to find a way now to switch overflow:hidden/visible depending on the sidebar`s state open/closed etc...

Comment: no worries :)) I have answered if you wouldn't mind accepting ? Happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
overflow: visible ?
```

[JQuery Dragging Outside Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656258/jquery-dragging-outside-parent)

OR

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
        appendTo: 'body', // Append to the body.
        zIndex: <someNumberYouThinkIsAppropriateHere>,
        containment: $('document'),
        helper: 'clone'
    });
```

[Drag item outside parent and into UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569407/drag-item-outside-parent-and-into-ui-dialog)

Comment: The overflow:visible was the right track, because one of my parents has overflow:hidden set.!